# I can't see my iads on my iPhone. But on simulator they work

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, iad

While I'm testing my app on iOS Simulator, I can see ads.
But if I turn on this app on my iPhone, I can't see them.

I use this:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

Where can be a problem?

I set NSLog on both methods. Each time when I turn on this app on my iPhone, I got the log from didFailToReceiveAdWithError.

Error says:

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x8892fd0 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}

Comment: And what does the `error` say?

Comment: @duskwuff I edited my question. There you can see the `error`.

Comment: I assume you've properly setup your profiles and application to support iAd. iAd is not working within all countries. If your country is not supported you will get this result.

Comment: I have a feeling Apple is having issues with iAd, people everywhere have been companying about random errors from them.